# How to connect board outlines - EAGLE

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I've designed a particular shape PCB with 2 round corners using arc tools. Since I needed precise dimensions I've set them when I was drawing PCB outline. The problem is that PCB outline now isn't closed and I'm unable to connect open ends becouse they don't match exactly. This create me some problems. I've also tryed to set grid to finest and place ends very near, but nothing, they don't join.

Someone can advice me how I can solve this?

Comment: what grid size are you using? Probably you need to decrease the gird size.

Comment: if you press shift the grid will also go finer

Answer (score 4):

use the Info tool from the toolbox and click on the arc, there you can specify the coordinates so that the two arcs join perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from editing the coordinates by hand as @lalamer suggests, you could *Ctrl+Click* on the line end and snap it onto the grid.